# Constrain a 16 bit signed value between 0 and 4095 using Bit Manipulation only (without branching)

Tags: c++, c, optimization, bit-manipulation, branchless

I want to constrain the value of a `signed short` variable between 0 and 4095, after which I take the most significant 8 bits as my final value for use elsewhere. Right now I'm doing it in a basic manner as below:

```
short color     = /* some external source */;
/* 
 * I get the color value as a 16 bit signed integer from an
 * external source I cannot trust. 16 bits are being used here
 * for higher precision.
 */

if ( color < 0 ) {
    color = 0;
}
else if ( color > 4095 ) {
    color = 4095;
}

unsigned char color8bit  = 0xFF & (color >> 4);
/*
 * color8bit is my final value which I would actually use
 * in my application.
 */
```

Is there any way this can be done using bit manipulation only, i.e. without using any conditionals? It might help quite a bit in speeding things up as this operation is happening thousands of time in the code.

The following won't help as it doesn't take care of edge cases such as negative values and overflows:

```
unsigned char color8bit = 0xFF & (( 0x0FFF & color ) >> 4 );
```

**Edit:** [Adam Rosenfield's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12308926/1044750) is the one which takes the correct approach but its incorrectly implemented. [ouah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309664/1044750) gives correct results but takes a different approach that what I originally intended to find out.

This is what I ended up using:

```
const static short min = 0;
const static short max = 4095;
color = min ^ (( min ^ color ) & -( min < color ));
color = max ^ (( color ^ max ) & -( color < max ));
unsigned char color8bit = 0xFF & (( 0x0FFF & color ) >> 4 );
```

Comment: what if you cast to unsigned as the first step in that "the following won't help" bit?

Comment: Why not an unsigned short? Then for -ve values it would unsigned overflow (which is not UB), then you could just bitmask for 4095 (which is `(1 << 12) - 1`).

Comment: can the value really be negative?

Comment: If you want less than zero to always be zero and greater than 4095 to always be 4095, then it's difficult/messy to do it without if statements.  If you're content to have < 0 and > 4095 "folded" then it's fairly easy/simple.

Comment: @H2CO3 The signed value for the bits is completely different for the same unsigned value if the number is negative. Semantically it should be then clamped to 0 if its a negative no.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, excellent question.  I wouldn't know what a negative color would represent.  Sounds like the external source should be giving you an unsigned value.  OP, can you perform an (unsigned short) cast immediately upon receiving the value from the external source?

Comment: You might find this enlightening: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fastest-way-to-clamp-an-integer-to-the-range-0-255

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Semantically no, but since I cannot trust the source from where I'm getting a negative value, I have to do a sanity check.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, negative values are quite easy to obtain if any filtering was applied to the source.

Comment: @wnraman, do negatives have to go to zero?  If not, then you could cast to unsigned int, then do your solution.  You will get 0xFFF if the value was less than 0.  Maybe okay, maybe not.  Does black and white really matter anyway between friends :-)

Comment: Will a simple `>> 4` really convert to 8 bits for you? If this is an imaging application, the 12 bit value is probably linear while the 8 bit value would need to be gamma corrected.

Comment: @MarkRansom, good point, if the external source is using 5:6:5 bit layout for the color channels in the 16 bits, then the >> 4 will give weird colors, but this is maybe off topic to the original question.

Comment: The net-net is that there are several ways to do it, but most will be no faster than the relatively straight-forward logic above.  An interesting intellectual exercise, but of little practical value.

Comment: @MarkRansom I actually intended to do the `and` with `0x0FFF` to clamp down to 12 bits. I've updated the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
short color = /* ... */
color =   ((((!!(color >> 12)) * 0xFFF)) | (!(color >> 12) * color ))
        & (!(color >> 15) * 0xFFF);

unsigned char color8bit  = 0xFF & (color >> 4);
```

It assumes two's complement representation.

This has the advantage of not using any equality or relational operators. There are situations you want to avoid branches at all costs: in some security applications you don't want the attackers to perform branch predictions. Without branches (in embedded processors particularly) you can make your function run in constant time for all inputs.

Note that: `x * 0xFFF` can be further reduced to `(x << 12) - x`.  Also the multiplication in `(!(color >> 12) * color )` can also be further optimized as the left operand of `*` here is `0` or `1`.

**EDIT:**

I add a little explanation: the expression above simply does the same as below without the use of the conditional and relational operators:

```
y =   ((y > 4095 ? 4095 : 0) | (y > 4095 ? 0 : y))
    & (y < 0 ? 0 : 4095);
```

**EDIT2:**

as @HotLicks correctly noted in his comment, the `!` is still a conceptual branch. Nevertheless it can also be computed with bitwise operators. For example `!!a` can be done with the trivial:

```
b = (a >> 15 | a >> 14 | ... | a >> 1 | a) & 1
```

and `!a` can be done as `b ^ 1`.  And I'm sure there is a nice hack to do it more effectively.

Comment: Note that the `!` operator is a conceptual branch, similar to `>` and `<`.

Comment: @HotLicks I added an edit to my answer to mention this point.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, see [these bit-twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax):

```
short color = ...;
color = color ^ (color & -(color < 0));  // color = max(color, 0)
color = 4096 ^ ((color ^ 4096) & -(color < 4096));  // color = min(color, 4096)

unsigned char color8bit  = 0xFF & (color >> 4);
```

Whether this actually turns out to be faster, I don't know -- you should profile.  Most modern x86 and x86-64 chips these days support "conditional move" instructions (cmov) which conditionally store a value depending on the EFLAGS status bits, and optimizing compilers will often produce these instructions from ternary expressions like `color >= 0 ? color : 0`.  Those will likely be fastest, but they won't run on older x86 chips.

Comment: Arguably you're doing conditionals that would be branches on many machines.

Comment: @HotLicks, many processors (x86 in particular) have instructions to spread a conditional bit out into an entire register.

Comment: True, but there are also compilers that would flatten the `if` statements in the original scheme into non-branching ops.

Comment: I've done some bit-twiddling tests, and in my case it wasn't the fastest method. Sorry to show this link twice in the same question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fastest-way-to-clamp-an-integer-to-the-range-0-255

Comment: I spent half of yesterday on that Standford site trying to come up with something similar on my own but completely ignored min and max parts. Thanks a lot :) When I move on to some complex rendering, I'll try to do some profiling to see if there are substantial advantages.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that many processors have conditional mov instructions. GCC definitely takes advantage of this for x64, and MSVC does to at least some extent (my quick-n-dirty check indicates that it still does a branch if `(color >= 0)`). An ARM target will also use conditional instructions to avoid branches.

Comment: Yes, the instruction `move regA to regC if condition true else move regB to regC` or something similar is fairly common.  This makes it possible for a halfway decent compiler to convert the simple `if` statements above to non-branching instruction sequences.  (Though, oddly, better code will likely be produced WITHOUT the `else`.)

Comment: @MichaelBurr -- Try your compile test again, but remove the `else`.  This should eliminate the branch due to `if (color < 0)`.

Comment: @HotLicks: that doesn't seem to remove the branch (tried `/Ox`, `/O2`, and `/Ot` on VS 2010 and VS 2012).

Comment: @MichaelBurr -- Odd.  `if (color < 0) color = 0;` should compile into a compare and conditional move.

Comment: @MichaelBurr -- I'll bet it has something to do with pipelining.  If you copy color to color2 before the first test and test that for the second test (but still set color) then the compiler would be more comfortable squeezing the stuff together.

Comment: @HotLicks: the `color2` temp did the trick. It results in a couple of conditional moves being used and no branches for an MSVC x64 build.

Comment: @MichaelBurr -- Yep, it seems somewhat counter-intuitive, but the compiler doesn't want the second compare to wait for the possible assignment from the first if.  And of course if you code if/else then that must generate a branch to match the logic of the source.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

```
BYTE data[0x10000] = { ..... };

BYTE byte_color = data[(unsiged short)short_color];
```

In your days 64kb table is not something outrageous and may be acceptable. The number of assembler commands in this variant of code will be absolute minimum compared to other possible approaches.

Comment: Actually, you only need a 128K bit table, to tell you whether to set 0 or 4095 or leave alone.

Comment: You are right but from the speed point of view it is better to get the result just in one step.

Comment: @HotLicks, your optimization would bring us right back to needing a branch.

Comment: These days a 128kb table doesn't take an appreciable chunk of the available RAM, but it does make a good cache killer. Calculating a value is faster than getting it from uncached RAM, even with a branch.

Comment: @MarkRansom -- Untrue.  Propagate one bit into a 12 bit OR mask and the other bit into a 12 bit AND mask and OR/AND those with the source number.

Comment: True, but this depends on the architecture. Small chip may have no cache at all.

Comment: you could write a lookup table that's a bit field instead of an array of bytes. the population of the table and the lookup test are slightly slower but the size of the table shrinks to 1/8th

Comment: @cppguy -- That's what I suggested above.

Answer (score 2):

I assume a `short` is 16 bits.

Remove negative values:

```
int16_t mask=-(int16_t)((uint16_t)color>>15);//0xFFFF if +ve, 0 if -ve
short value=color&mask;//0 if -ve, colour if +ve
```

`value` is now between 0 and 32767 inclusive.

You can then do something similar to clamp the value:

```
mask=(uint16_t)(value-4096)>>15;//1 if <=4095, 0 if >4095
--mask;//0 if <=4095, 0xFFFF if >4095
mask&=0xFFF;//0 if <=4095, 4095 if >4095

value|=mask;//4095 if >4095, color if <4095
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also easily vectorize this using [Intel's SSE intrinsics](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/9/4/c/8/e/18072-347603.pdf).  One 128-bit register would hold 8 of your `short` and there are functions to min/max/shift/mask all of them in parallel.  In a loop the constants for min/max can be preloaded into a register.  The `pshufb` instruction (part of SSSE3) will even pack the bytes for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to leave an answer even though it doesn't directly answer the original question, because in the end I think you'll find it much more useful.

I'm assuming that your color is coming from a camera or image scanner running at 12 bits, followed by some undetermined processing step that might create values beyond the 0 to 4095 range. If that's the case the values are almost certainly derived in a linear fashion. The problem is that displays are gamma corrected, so the conversion from 12 bit to 8 bit will require a non-linear gamma function rather than a simple right shift. This will be much slower than the clamping operation your question is trying to optimize. If you don't use a gamma function the image will appear too dark.

```
short color     = /* some external source */;
unsigned char color8bit;
if (color <= 0)
    color8bit = 0;
else if (color >= 4095)
    color8bit = 255;
else
    color8bit = (unsigned char)(255.99 * pow(color / 4095.0, 1/2.2));
```

At this point you might consider a lookup table [as suggested by Kirill Kobelev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12308911/5987).

Comment: Actually, the `color` variable here represents only 1 color channel at any time. The code above is in an `inline` function being called for each color component one by one so gamma correction doesn't yet apply, but its good to know as I will be needing it in the next few weeks.

The answer provided by @ouah is the actually the correct one, without conditionals.

Comment: @vvnraman, gamma correction has to be applied at the conversion to 8 bits so that the full resolution can be used. If you do it later then you'll get some horrible blocking artifacts in the dark areas. It can be applied to each color channel independently.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat akin to Tom Seddon's answer, but uses a slightly cleaner way to do the clamp above.  Note that both Mr. Seddon's answer and mine avoid the issue of ouah's answer that shifting a signed value to the right is implementation defined behavior, and hence not guaranteed to work on all architenctures.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <iostream>

int16_t clamp(int16_t value)
{
    // clampBelow is 0xffff for -ve, 0x0000 for +ve
        int16_t const clampBelow = -static_cast<int16_t>(static_cast<uint16_t>(value) >> 15);

    // value is now clamped below at zero
    value &= ~clampBelow;
    // subtract 4095 so we can do the same trick again
    value -= 4095;
    // clampAbove is 0xffff for -ve, 0x0000 for +ve,
    // i.e. 0xffff for original value < 4095, 0x0000 for original >= 4096
        int16_t const clampAbove = -static_cast<int16_t>(static_cast<uint16_t>(value) >> 15);

    // adjusted value now clamped above at zero
    value &= clampAbove;
    // and restore to original value.
    value += 4095;
    return value;
}

void verify(int16_t value)
{
    int16_t const clamped = clamp(value);
    int16_t const check = (value < 0 ? 0 : value > 4095 ? 4095 : value);
    if (clamped != check)
    {
        std::cout << "Verification falure for value: " << value << ", clamped: " << clamped << ", check: " << check << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    for (int16_t i = 0x4000; i != 0x3fff; i++)
    {
        verify(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That's a full test program (OK, so it doesn't test 0x3fff - sue me. ;) ) from which you can extract the `clamp()` routine for whatever you need.

I've also broken clamp out to "one step per line" for the sake of clarity.  If your compiler has a half way decent optimizer, you can leave it as is and rely on the compiler to produce the best possible code.  If your compiler's optimizer is not that great, then by all means, it can be reduced in line count, albeit at the cost of a little readability.

"Never sacrifice clarity for efficiency" -- Bob Buckley, comp sci professor, U-Warwick, Coventry, England, 1980.

Best piece of advice I ever got. ;)